# Is there a way to create domains and subdomains in Apache like this?

Tags: apache2

I'm a web programmer that has finally been tasked with setting up a development server for in house development and testing. I'm a novice when it comes to setting up a LAMP server. I've only ever managed to do the default LAMP stack with "tasksel", never managed to get multiple domains working properly.

What I would like to know is, is it possible to drop a single config file for a single domain/subdomain in a directory in order to configure it? I have a feeling this is how you use the directory /sites-available/ right?

Any tips in the right direction are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that is indeed how multiple subdomains are managed in Apache. You created a configuration in `sites-available`, and then enable them using the `a2ensite` command. For example, I have a local Ubuntu mirror and a repository set up on the same server: [mirror](http://paste.ubuntu.com/8156484/)  (saved as `/etc/apache2/sites-available/default.conf`)and [repo](http://paste.ubuntu.com/8156477/) (saved as `/etc/apache2/sites-available/repo.conf`. Then I enable them thus (`sudo` or root needed):

```
a2ensite default
a2ensite repo
service apache2 reload
```

With proper DNS configuration, now `repo.fqdn` and `mirror.fqdn`, while resolving to the same IP, open the correct sites.

Comment: Would you mind posting the contents of your default.conf for me to see how you did it? Remove any personal information of course

Comment: @Wh33t I have posted both configuration files. There are links above.

Comment: Gah, for some reason this isn't working.

Here is my dev.conf which I've created in /etc/apache2/sites-enabled
`<VirtualHost 192.168.0.2>
ServerName dev.server
ServerAlias server
DocumentRoot /var/www/html/subs/dev
</VirtualHost>`

It appears to add correctly using a2ensite dev and I've reloaded the service yet it still brings me to the default directory when viewed over the web. 

Any ideas?

Comment: I think I've got it now. It appears as though service apache2 reload requires SUDO in front of it. I also manually installed apache, php and mysql without using tasksel and that might have made some difference as well.